# For loop being missed out in Android

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have an activity in Android that takes the result of a web service and puts it into an adapter to display a list of items.  I've created a listener interface for this called `OnLoadCompleteListener` and my listener for this activity looks like

```
mListener = new OnLoadCompleteListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(RootWebService service) {
        if(service instanceof WebService) {
            //gets the number of items
            int total = ((WebService) service).getCount();
            for(int i=0; i<total; ++i) {
                //Log.d("ITEM", "inserting " + i);
                Item item = ((WebService) service).get(i);
                //our adapter class automatically receives items
                mAdapter.addItem(item);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now this is the bizarre bit: the listener is getting hit, `total` is being set to 12 (the number of items I asked for) and then the for loop is being bypassed altogether.  The adapter remains empty and the screen displays pretty much nothing.

However, if the commented out `Log.d(...)` call is made active, the loop works.

Why?  The callback is being run from the UI thread, the `getCount()` method is returning the correct value, and this adapter has worked before.  What on earth is happening?

By the way, `mAdapter` is an instance of a subclass of `Adapter` I wrote for the purpose, and the `addItem(Item)` method looks like this:

```
public synchronized void addItem(Item item) {
    mItems.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`mItems` is exactly what you would expect.

Comment: Did you debug it and see if the program really enters the for loop or skips it altogether?

Comment: Yes, I stepped through the code.  It leaps right over the `for` loop.

Comment: Are you sure total is greater than 0?

Comment: Log the total before the loop with and without other log.

Comment: `mAdapter` is an `Adapter` that populates a `ListView`.  It works fine.  I just logged `total` with a `Log.d(...)` statement while stepping through and it confirms `total` is indeed 12.

Comment: One of the reasons for it could be that the WebService takes a while to finish the call... Log calls are slow. Maybe a small thread.sleep() before the loop would say more? Maybe watching the 'total' var could prove to be useful?

Comment: The `WebService` has already finished before this call is made; it's only after that that this method is called from a `Runnable` on the UI thread.  I did wonder about the log call being slow but as I say I've logged total as being 12 using `Log.d(...)` and THEN it has STILL skipped the loop, so I'm pretty sure it's not that.

Comment: You cant say its completely skipped, where are you checking the actual amount of items in the adapter? Because you don't see the items doesn't mean they are not in the adapter.

Comment: The `addItem(Item)` method *is not being called*.  I *have* checked this.  I wrote the subclass of `Adapter` and I have looked at this.  The `for` loop is not being hit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do something like `invalidate` or something along those lines which pretty much just refreshes the data in the adapter.

I think its this.

`myListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

If that doesn't work it could be...

`myListView.invalidate();`

Comment: It's not the adapter that's the problem: it's the fact that the code that populates the adapter isn't being hit because the `for` loop isn't running.

Comment: also getListView().postInvalidate()

Comment: Well I dont see you notifying the data has changed, and the for loop appears to be working as it logs, a log call that's taken out won't disable a for loop.

Comment: The `for` loop definitely isn't running.  I stepped through the code.

Comment: Also the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method is actually called in the `addItem(Item)` method, after the item is added to the adapter's list.

Comment: Well I see twp conditionals that aren't directly controlled by you it appears, one of those two are causing it. One being the if statement, if that returned FALSE then the for loop would be entirely bypassed, the second being the condition inside the for loop statement. One of them is causing the problem...

Comment: The fact that total is being set to 12 (and I've logged this) suggests it's not the `if` statement.  No idea what could be going wrong with the `for` statement, hence the question.

Comment: Just suggesting possibilities here. The only thing that could stop the for loop is that condition sorry. If it skips completely then its the first condition in the for loop. Sorry I don't see anything else that could effect this.

Comment: I was wondering if the compiler had decided this was "do-nothing" code and optimized it out maybe.  I do sometimes see it "condense" two lines into one when stepping through code.

Comment: I have a similar issue...curious how this plays out.